# How to get a object type at the moment of object instantiation C#.

Tags: c#, reflection, types, instance

I created a table in a database with a fields definition, I mean TableName, ColumnName.
Then I created a class which has all the structure of the table.
Then I created a Property GetObjectType()

What I want is to at the moment of the instantiation the Property GetObjectType is already loaded with the information of the property by reflection.

I did something like this.

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    private Type boType;
    private string tableName;
    private string fieldName;

    public strig TableName{
            //Get and set
    }

    public strig FieldName{
            //Get and set
    }

    public Type GetObjectType
    {
        get
        {
            if(boType == null)
            {
                this.boType = Type.GetType("NameSpace" + this.FieldName, NameSpace"));
            }
            return this.boType;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
Type myType = obj.GetObjectType(); //Always null'
```

I'm in the correct way?

Comment: It seems you're reimplementing the wheel. Why don't you just use the GetType() method that you inherit from the base class?

Comment: It's not the type of my object. I want a type from my two properties (TableName, FieldName)

Comment: Oh, that's not going to work. GetType only returns types whose meta data really exists, meaning types that are really defined in your code. What you probably want is get some kind of identifier for your types. You'll have to do that manually, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

use GetType()directly. you dont have to write a custom GetObjectType() method for it.

like below,

```
Myclass obj=new MyClass();
Type type=obj.GetType();
```

Answer (score 0):

Every object has the method GetType() on it due to inheritance from System.Object

Just do:

```
 MyClass obj = new MyClass();
 Type myType = obj.GetType();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint inside the GetObjectType function and test your line of code in the Immediate Window at execution time. I'm guessing that your class name/namespace doesn't exactly match what you are expecting.